# React Native `RuntimeError: abort(Error: xcrun exited with non-zero code: 2` on iOS simulator

Tags: xcode, react-native, expo, ios-simulator

I was working on a React Native project with a group and was asked to use the iPhone 13 simulator as a model while working. I only had access to the iPhone 12 simulator, and I saw that my XCode was a version behind, so I updated it. Now with the new XCode, I am getting an error when I start the React Native server and try and open the iOS simulator. the error is shown below:

[image: error code in console]

Running this command with the suggested `build with -s Assertions=1` reveals the following:

[image: result of build command with flag]

My package.json is as following:

[image: packagejson file]

Any idea what is going on or how to proceed?  Expo seems to be able to run, but trying to open the simulator crashes the server. The project I am on is near tight deadlines and I am totally held up by this. Either a way to troubleshoot this error or a way to roll back my XCode install and just live with a dated simulator would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 36):

Figured it our thanks to ShepSims from https://github.com/expo/expo-cli/issues/2413 . Before being able to open the iOS simulator from the terminal, I needed to open XCode and open the simulator there. This mounts the simulator bundle, allowing later access by pressing `i` after running `expo start`.

Answer (score 15):

I was receiving the same error as above with XCode command line tools installed only, no XCode installed.

I tried re-installing XCode command line tools which didn't do anything.

For me this was solved with advice mentioned at https://github.com/expo/expo-cli/issues/3871:

- open `Simulator.app`, as it automatically sets the default device.

Comment: Opening the Simulator.app did it for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

The fastest way from my point of view is "spotlight" (Cmd+Space) search for "Simulator", hit enter before running "expo start" in your terminal.

Comment: Thank you this really helped me. I was having the exact same issue after Xcode auto-updated.

Answer (score 4):

It is not anything. It was solved by opening simulator from XCOde on my mac

Answer (score 4):

Suddenly, I got this same error on Mac OS 14 (Sonoma). I solved it by installing iOS (v17) from XCode.

XCode -> Settings -> Platforms - Get button on iOS row

[image]

Once download completed, the simulator started a default device. Also this solved the empty OS in the new simulator window (see below)
[image]

Comment: Had the problem as soon as I updated XCode. Reinstalling the platforms was the only thing that worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve the problem by using this command

```
sudo expo start
```

Or

```
manually open simulator

start app: react-native run-ios

manually do: Hardware -> Device -> select iOS -> select Device (different than before !)

that will open a second simulator

start the app again: react-native run-ios (expo start then press i)

this opens the app in the selected simulator
```

Note:- please stay open the silumater then press the i in the expo and same for the react-native run-ios command

Answer (score 0):

I addressed this issue (twice now) using `fastlane` (`brew install fastlane`):

1. Reinstall all simulators: `fastlane snapshot reset_simulators`
2. Open **Simulator** manually (this is important)
3. Relaunch your React Native app from the CLI or however else you do it

*Note: This will wipe out all your current simulators so just make sure you haven't done any special configuration in/on them that you'll need to keep. But otherwise it should be a quickfix.*