# Xcode issue - scrub exited with non-zero code: 2

Tags: reactjs, xcode, react-native, expo, npx

Opening on iOS...

xcrun exited with non-zero code: 2

An error was encountered processing the command (domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain, code=2):

Unable to boot device because we cannot determine the runtime bundle.

No such file or directory

```
at ChildProcess.completionListener (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/@expo/spawn-async/src/spawnAsync.ts:65:13)
    at Object.onceWrapper (node:events:628:26)
    at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:513:28)
    at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1091:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:302:5)
    ...
    at spawnAsync (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/@expo/spawn-async/src/spawnAsync.ts:26:19)
    at xcrunAsync (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/xdl/src/SimControl.ts:427:28)
    at runBootAsync (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/xdl/src/SimControl.ts:217:11)
    at bootAsync (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/xdl/src/SimControl.ts:189:9)
    at action (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/xdl/src/SimControl.ts:142:19)
    at waitForActionAsync (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/xdl/src/apple/utils/waitForActionAsync.ts:17:22)
    at waitForDeviceToBootAsync (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/xdl/src/SimControl.ts:141:28)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/xdl/src/utils/profileMethod.ts:22:21
    at ensureSimulatorOpenAsync (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/xdl/src/Simulator.ts:234:80)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
```

None of the other stack overflow solutions have worked pls help!

Comment: I got around this by simply opening the Simulator app per [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69804969/react-native-runtimeerror-aborterror-xcrun-exited-with-non-zero-code-2-on)